# Eclipse plugin/property spinner/loading icon

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, loading

I create eclipse plugins... I have mainly created wizards and properties. I am mainly thinking about the properties that I have created. When the user clicks the "Apply" button, sometimes it takes a few seconds to execute. Is there a good loading icon that can be used while an eclipse plugin/property is working? Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

In wizards, you can probably show progressmonitor, and update the progress during your business logic gets executed on click apply.

**Added information which makes more sense to be part of answer**

Currently it is not supported in eclipse to add your custom progress monitor.https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=43699. But you can use jobs to perform long running operation which will allow eclipse to close the properties page and complete your logic in the background job.

Comment: What about properties?

Comment: Currently it is not supported in eclipse to add your custom progress monitor.https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=43699. But you can use jobs to perform long running operation which will allow eclipse to close the properties page and complete your logic in the background job.